# Fix magento 1.9 installation error "Invalid backend name []"

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, backend, installation, request

When we install Magento 1.9 it shows: There has been an error processing your request Invalid backend name. How do i fix this?

[image]

Comment: In app/etc/local.xml please check 
<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>

Answer (score 0):

I have already faced this issue. In your `app/etc/` folder other than local.xml some backup file in end with `.xml` file. you can change delete that file.

Comment: app/etc/folder local.xml.additional.xml  or local.xml.template .xml  file available not local.xml

Comment: create local.xml file and configure and remove  local.xml.additional.xml it will work

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a misconfigured `local.xml` for **cache backend**

Edit local.xml

Remove all code between and the cache tags

```
<cache>

</cache>
```

Then delete contents of var/cache/ folder in Magento.